# how to get custom options selected value in shipping address city field on ceckout page?

Tags: magento

How to get custom options selected value in shipping address city field? actually I want whatever user select delivery city from drop-down field that city must pre-filled in shipping address city field?

Comment: Please explain your question clearly. If possible provide some screenshots. Have you created custom option named city or you want from billing address?

Comment: I have a custom option with the name delivery city. i want when user select a city from it and make checkout that time the selected city from this field populate in city field on shipping address.

Comment: Why do you keep city as custom options. if customer add two product in cart with two different city then will there not be conflict?

Comment: I want that a customer select one order at a time. Please help me...........